# What magic in "our" or "use vars" satisfies "use strict qw(vars)"?

Tags: perl, language-lawyer, package, variable-declaration, scoping

I have working code, but I am trying to understand *why* it works. I am also trying to learn more about the internals of Perl 5 (`perlbrew`, `perl-5.26.1`, `Cygwin x64`).

I know from [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and [`strict`](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.26.1/lib/strict.pm) that `use strict 'vars'` works by setting flags in `$^H`.  Perl then tests accesses to non-`::` variables based on those flags.  Somehow, both `our` and `use vars` mark variables so that they will pass the test.  How do they do so?

For example:

```
perl -E 'package Foo;
    use strict "vars";
    use vars qw($foo);
    say $foo;'
```

runs fine (although it produces no output).  Based on [the source for `use vars`](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.26.1/lib/vars.pm#L29), I tried this, which I thought would have the same effect:

```
perl -E 'package Foo;
    use strict "vars";
    my $sym = "Foo::foo";          # <-- These two lines pulled straight
    *$sym = \$$sym;                # <-- from the source for the vars pragma
    say $foo;'
```

However, it gave me an error: `Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name`.  I also tried `$sym = "::Foo:foo"` in the above, with the same result.

I checked, and `$Foo::foo` is in the symbol table:

```
$ perl -E 'package Foo;
      use Data::Dumper;
      use strict "vars"; 
      my $sym = "Foo::foo";
      *$sym = \$$sym; 
      say Dumper(\%{"Foo::"});'    # <-- Foo's symbol table

Output: 
$VAR1 = {
    'BEGIN'  => *Foo::BEGIN,
    'Dumper' => *Foo::Dumper,
    'foo'    => *Foo::foo          # <-- yep, it's there
};
```

What else is `use vars` doing that I'm missing?  Does `our` do the same, or something different?

#### Update

Here's an A/B based on [melpomene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49739472/2877364):

```
Fails                         Succeeds
-------------------------     ----------------------------------
package Foo;                  package Foo;
use strict "vars";            use strict "vars";

                              BEGIN {
                                  package Bar;
my $sym="Foo::foo";               my $sym = "Foo::foo";
*$sym = \$$sym;                   *$sym = \$$sym;
                              }
say $foo;                     say $foo;
```

Comment: The lexical variables declared by `my`, `state` and `our` exempt from strict. `use vars` creates a package variable in a different package and imports it, taking advantage of the fact that imported variables are exempt from strict.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> `use strict 'vars'` works by setting flags in `$^H`.

Yes, but that's an implementation detail. `$^H` exposes some internal interpreter state bits, but you're not supposed to touch it in normal code.

> Somehow, both `our` and `use vars` mark variables so that they will pass the test. How do they do so?

This is also considered an implementation detail.

---

However, we can peek a bit under the hood. `strict "vars"` complains about undeclared variables (at compile time).

There is a hardcoded list of variables that are exempt from this check; it includes all punctuation variables (e.g. `$/`, `$_`, etc. along with `$a` and `$b` (used by `sort`)).

All lexically (i.e. locally) declared variables also pass `strict`; this is how `my`, `our`, and `state` work. (For our purposes [`local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local()) is not a declaration and does not create local variables; `local` temporarily changes the value of an existing variable.)

The third exception is variables exported from modules. Using global variables as part of your module interface is generally considered to be a bad idea, but some older modules still do it. [`English`](https://metacpan.org/pod/English) also exports variables because that's its whole point, so we'll use it as an example:

```
use strict;
use English qw($INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR);
$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "";  # <--
my $paragraph = readline STDIN;
```

The line marked `<--` does not throw an error because Perl remembers which variables were imported from a module.

What does "exporting" actually mean? It just means aliasing a symbol across package boundaries:

```
*main::foo = \$Some::Module::foo;  # now $main::foo is an alias for $Some::Module::foo
```

The curious thing is that as far as the Perl internals are concerned, a variable is "imported" if it has been aliased in some other package. It does not matter what it was aliased *to*; all that matters is where the aliasing happened. `use vars` (ab-)uses this detail to bypass `strict "vars"` by exporting your own variables back at you:

```
package Some::Package;
use vars qw($foo);
```

works like

```
package Some::Package;
BEGIN {
    package vars;
    *Some::Package::foo = \$Some::Package::foo;
}
# now $foo is an alias to ... itself
```

The other piece of the puzzle is that `use` happens at compile time, like `BEGIN` blocks. Your example fails because your aliasing attempt only happens at runtime, which is too late for `strict`, and because it doesn't switch to a different package to do the aliasing.

---

In the end `vars` is just a module, written in plain Perl. `our` is different: It is a real keyword and part of the language. It also has different behavior: It effectively creates an alias (to a package variable), but that alias lives in a local scope, not the symbol table.

Consider e.g. the following:

```
my $foo = 2;
{
    our $foo = "hello";
    print "foo = $foo; main::foo = $main::foo\n";
}
print "foo = $foo; main::foo = $main::foo\n";
```

This outputs

```
foo = hello; main::foo = hello
foo = 2; main::foo = hello
```

because the inner `our $foo` declaration shadows the outer `$foo` in the inner block. Within the block both `$foo` and `$main::foo` refer to the same variable; outside `$foo` refers to the lexical `my $foo`, which is untouched.

Another difference to `use vars`:

```
use strict;
package Foo;
our $x = "hello";
package Bar;
print "$x\n";  # hello
```

This code works fine because `package` declarations don't create a new scope. There is only one unit of scoping here (the whole file), and so `our $x` makes `$x` refer to `$Foo::x` for the rest of the file, no matter which package you switch into.

On the other hand:

```
use strict;
package Foo;
use vars qw($x);
$x = "hello";
package Bar;
print "$x\n";
```

This code doesn't even compile. The reference to `$x` in the last line can't be resolved: Perl checks the local scope first, but there are no locally declared `$x`'s. It then checks the current package (`Bar`) and finds nothing either, and without `strict "vars"` it would have automatically created `$Bar::x` for you, but with `strict "vars"` enabled this is simply an error. `$Foo::x` is irrelevant and never checked.

Comment: Yes, magic indeed!  To confirm, is this correct?--- `our` doesn't need to trigger "exported if aliased when in a different package" because it is updating the local scope (scratchpad).  Perl checks the local scope and finds the `our` variable before it checks the symbol table for an exported variable.

Comment: @cxw That's correct, but I haven't heard the term "scratchpad" in this context before. There's a thing called a "(lexical) pad", which is a data structure used to implement local scopes in the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks very much!  This is very helpful - I'm pretty sure I would not have figured it out even if I had tried spelunking in the C source.  (I got scratchpad from [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=728484), but I'll use "lexical pad" in future.)

Comment: @cxw Oh, interesting. If that link is right, "pad" is just a shortened name for "scratchpad".